# Partial fraction of $\frac{2x^2-9x-9}{x^3-9x}$

Tags: partial-fractions

I'm doing some questions from Anton, 8th edition, page 543, question 13. I've found a answer but it does not match with the answer given at the last pages.

Questions asks to solve $\int{\frac{2x^2-9x-9}{x^3-9x}}$

So:

### $$\frac{2x^2-9x-9}{x(x^2-9)}$$

then:

### $$\frac{2x^2-9x-9}{x(x-3)(x+3)}$$

(using  $a(x-x')(x-x'')$)

Continuing:

### $$2x^2-9x-9 = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{(x-3)} + \frac{C}{(x+3)}$$

Solving the product:

$$A(x^2-9)+Bx(x+3)+Cx(x-3)$$

Ended up with a system, because: $(A+B+C)x^2+(3B-3C)x+(-9A)$
\begin{cases} A+B+C =2 \\ 3B-3C = -9 \\ -9A = -9\end{cases}

then:

$A = 1$

$B = -1$

$C = 2$

The answer I found:

$$ ln |x| - ln|x-3| + 2 ln|x+3| + C $$

answer given by author:

$$ ln |\frac{x(x+3)^2}{x-3}| + C$$

What am I missing?

Comment: Those are the same thing other than that the author is missing the $+C$

Comment: @AdamHughes actually I forgot the + C in the author's answer. Ty for pointing that out, though my misunderstanding was with properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're answer is fine and is equivalent to the author's.

To see why, recall:

$$\ln a - \ln b = \ln\left(\frac ab\right)$$

$$\ln a + \ln b = \ln(ab)$$

$$2 \ln a = \ln(a^2)$$

Comment: Is this true: $nln(a) = ln(a^n) | n\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes it is true. Correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using properties of logarithm ($\ln a + \ln b = \ln (ab)$) you have
$$\ln |x| - \ln |x-3|  + 2 \ln |x+3| = \ln \frac{|x|(x+3)^2}{|x-3|}$$